# A fast way to fill an dataset with same values of compound data in h5py

Tags: numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have a large dataset of compound data in a hdf file. The Type of the compound data looks as following:

```
    numpy.dtype([('Image', h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference)), 
                 ('NextLevel', h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference))])
```

With that I create a dataset with references to an image and another dataset at each position.
These datasets have the dimensions n x n, with n typically at least 256, but more likely >2000. 
I have to initially fill each position of these datasets with the same value:

```
    [[(image.ref, dataset.ref)...(image.ref, dataset.ref)],
      .
      .
      .
     [(image.ref, dataset.ref)...(image.ref, dataset.ref)]]
```

I try to avoid filling it with two for-loops like:

```
    for i in xrange(0,n):
      for j in xrange(0,n):
         daset[i,j] =(image.ref, dataset.ref)
```

because the performance is very bad.
So I'm searching for something like `numpy.fill`, `numpy.shape`, `numpy.reshape`, `numpy.array`, `numpy.arrange`, `[:]` and so on. I tried those functions in various ways, but they all seem to work only with number and string datatypes. 
Is there any way to fill these datasets in a faster way then the for-loops?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either numpy [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) or a combination of `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.reshape`:

```
my_dtype = numpy.dtype([('Image', h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference)), 
             ('NextLevel', h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference))])
ref_array = array( (image.ref, dataset.ref), dtype=my_dtype)
dataset = numpy.repeat(ref_array, n*n)
dataset = dataset.reshape( (n,n) )
```

Note that `numpy.repeat` returns a flattened array, hence the use of `numpy.reshape`. It seems `repeat` is faster than just broadcasting it:

```
%timeit empty_dataset=np.empty(2*2,dtype=my_dtype); empty_dataset[:]=ref_array
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.09 us per loop

%timeit repeat_dataset=np.repeat(ref_array, 2*2).reshape((2,2))
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.92 us per loop
```